# How to install IE 6 up until IE 8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, internet-explorer, wine

Is there a way installing IE 6 up untill IE 8 on Ubuntu using Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I installed [Playonlinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/) for this (and other purposes), made it extremely easy to install Internet Explorer, and other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try [IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

Yes (see Iain's link), but it won't behave *exactly* the same as real IE versions. Whether it's on Windows or Linux, the ‘OS integration’ ensures that you can't have a reliable, genuine, multiple-IE install.

If your aim is proper, thorough testing of your websites across IE versions, the only option is to install each browser on a virtual machine. (I use VirtualBox, with an XP SP3 install copied three times, different IEs on each.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine).